# UItable Footer View issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I need to design the view with header, content view (table view) and footer view which is scrollable. Content view data will change dynamically. So I have used table view.

I have added the Header and footer view in the table view header and footer. (My goal is to scroll the header, content and footer view so the I have added my custom header and footer view in UItable view header and footer.)

My design:

[image]

It's working as per the design if the table view contains some data. Issue is, if table view doesn't contains any data (row count simply 0). The header view is display in the middle of the view (Table view frame shrink automatically in this case). Even I tried to handle the table view frame based on the data source count. But I can't.

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: what you want exactly ??

Comment: Some code would help.

Comment: My goal is to scroll the header, contact and footer view so the i have added my custom header and footer view in UItable view header and footer.

Comment: We need more details. Is this contact view a single fixed size cell? If that is the case, a UITableView is probably overkill for this.

Comment: what is your problem, like footer is not scrolling or content not increasing properly like that. Tell us exact problem and post some code for better understanding purpose.

Comment: Perhaps the contact view is a single cell of fixed size that contains another table view?

Comment: @CrimsonChris, Contact view is nothing but a collections of sections with row. Header view is added in the table view header section and footer view as well.

Comment: @Thukaram, My problem is footer view which i have added in the table view footer section should always in the bottom of the screen even the table view have no data.

Comment: Sounds to me like your "ContactView" should be a tableview and your blue and grey header/footer views should just be standard views. Layout all three views in the code or in the interface builder and then place them in a scroll view.

Comment: @CrimsonChris, Hope you know that Table view internally have UIScroll view. If we add the table view in the scroll i hope it should be difficult to handle the table view selection.

Comment: @Ganapathy The internal table view may contain a scrollview, but that doesn't mean it has to scroll. After you've loaded your cells, set the table view's height to be equal to the height of its contentSize.

Comment: @CrimsonChris, This will make scene. I will try that case and let you known. Thanks.

Comment: @Ganapathy,Try my code and let me if u find that useful or not .

Answer (score 0):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

You can use this code to customize footer height of UItableview

by putting valid if else

Comment: Problem is not in footer view Height. UITable view frame itself changing dynamically based on the content.

Answer (score 0):

Table view sections have a header view and a footer view. Between those are the cells for that particular section. It sounds like you want to simulate the existence of cells that don't really exist.

Perhaps what you really want is a standard `UIView` as your header and footer views with a `UITableView` in between. The `UITableView` won't change size based on its content and will scroll when independently of the header and footer views.

Comment: Actually You can see in the above screen, My footer and header view frame is some what huge. so if we set the header and footer view with static frame by default the visible cell of the table view is reduced so that i have designed to make the entire footer , content and header scrollable.

Comment: If you don't have any cells in your tableview but still have one section, then you should have your header followed by your footer with nothing in between.

Answer (score 0):

In a UItableView,The footer always appears at the end of section .But here you don't have any existance of cells and you want to show the footer at the bottom of the page .

Solution:

- Take one cell before getting data and set the height for that cell

  ```
  BOOL hasData;//Initialise in ViewDidLoad and set value according to data
  ```

> ```
> -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
> if (!hasdata) {
>     return 1;
> }else{
>     return dataArray.count;
> }
> }
> ```

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (!hasData) {
        cellHeight =
        self.view.frame.size.height -
        (tableViewHeaderHeight+tableViewFooterHeight);
    }else{
        //Set row height
    }
}
```

- and then after getting data for the tableview again reload that .

Hope this help you.Try this .It worked for me.